# How to know that a file is deleted or added (or any changes) in sdcard

Tags: android

I have a aplication in which i read the xml file that are stored in somewhere sdcard,then parse that xml and stored in database then my application work on that database.
But the sdcard is updated by client and insert new xml file,delete some old one.
so when any new file is added to the sdcard i want my service to start and parse it and save in database.
but how can i know that there is changes made in sdcard.myActivity class is :- SdcardActivity.java and service class is service class :- FileseacrchService.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [registerContentObserver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29)

```
    public final void registerContentObserver (Uri uri, 
                          boolean notifyForDescendents, ContentObserver observer)
```

> notifyForDescendents:-    If true changes to URIs beginning with uri will also cause notifications to be sent. If false only changes to the exact URI specified by uri will cause notifications to be sent. If true, than any URI values at or below the specified URI will also trigger a match.

Answer (score 1):

[FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) may be what you want.. Take a look at [this](http://www.roman10.net/android-fileobserverthe-underlying-inotify-mechanism-and-an-example/) example. Happy coding ;)

Comment: thank you Psyclops for your reply file Observer is more confusing.Please post some simple example that helps me.any help is appriciated

Comment: Never used it myself... From the documentation it seems that you must create a class extending FileObserver and override its onEvent method. then you can `FileObserver dir = new FileObserver("path/to/dir", FileObserver.EVENT_YOU_NEED);`

Comment: Thank you Psyclops.but A File Observer is attached to a folder, then only the files and sub-folders inside it are monitored, but its sub sub-folders and files are not. For example, there is a folder B inside folder A, and a folder C inside folder B. If a File Observer is created to monitor folder A, then any modifications done for folder B is detected, but not for folder C.But i want to detech the folder and subfolder and again sub sub folder.Please reply.Any help is appriciated.